# How do I center text along an SVG curve?

Tags: css, svg

Is there a way to center the text along a curve in SVG?

```html
<svg width="100" height="25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <path id="intermediate" d="M 7 5 C 25 25, 75 25, 93 5"/>
    </defs>
    <text fill="#105ca6">
        <textPath style="alignment-baseline: baseline;" xlink:href="#intermediate">Intermediate</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to use `startOffset="50%"`. The startOffset attribute defines an offset from the start of the path for the initial current text position. This will make the text to start in the middle of the path.

Next you need to use `text-anchor="middle"` to align the text around the starting point which in this case is the middle of the path.

```html
<svg width="100" height="25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <path id="intermediate" d="M 7 5 C 25 25, 75 25, 93 5" />
  </defs>
  <text fill="#105ca6">
    <textPath startOffset="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" xlink:href="#intermediate">Intermediate</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Side note: With SVG 2 (implementation [in progress](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5760616295825408)) you can define whether the text is rendered inward or outward with the new [`side`](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#text-TextPathElementSideAttribute) attribute on the [`textPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) element.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div style="max-width:90px; margin:0 auto">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg">
       <defs>
         <path id="intermediate" d="M 7 5 C 25 25, 75 25, 100 5"/>
       </defs>
       <text fill="#105ca6">
         <textPath style="alignment-baseline: baseline;" xlink:href="#intermediate">Intermediate</textPath></text>
     </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Only you have to wrap the svg code in division.
style is to add in parent div is : max-width to div and make it center using margin auto.
and its done...