# Make text curved with SVG, HTML and CSS for a web page title

Tags: html, css, svg

I want a html page title centered with a curve to it using SVG, CSS and HTML. The first letter should be the same height on the page as the last letter so it forms a half oval shape with the middle of the text elevated.

The closest I got was:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    
      <path id="MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red" d="M100,200
                 Q250,100 400,200" />
      <text class="title is-4">
        <textPath href="#MyPath" startOffset="80">
          Curved Title
        </textPath>
      </text>
</svg>
```

The red line doesn't need to be there, I only want the text.

I would like to have content below the SVG without a big gap, currently it pushes other elements in the div half way down the page with blank space.

I've looked at examples on stack overflow and the web, most of the text is either a full circle or text is uneven with the start or end of the title hanging lower or with an uneven shape. I want to be able to center it in a div with dynamic width.

Comment: please take a look at this recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71281977/how-do-i-center-text-along-an-svg-curve/71282958#71282958

Comment: The link helped to center the text in the svg. However the svg in the div is not centered. When I make small changes to try see what to do next, the svg either get's cropped, makes my div 3 x longer, completely disappears or changes the rounded corners of the div it's in. I'm not sure how to align it like a page title top and center of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can use `text-anchor` in combination with `pathLength` and `startOffset` to place the text in the middle. Here the the path length is 2, so the start offset is 1 and the anchor is set to "middle".

Second I changed the path a bit; scaled it and placed it in the top of the SVG (the arch hits y=0 in the middle). It is still the same shape. I used `dominant-baseline` to let the text "hang" under the path.

Now the viewbox can be scaled as well. If it has the height of 5 you can see the entire path, bit if you set it to 3 (second example) the following content will move closer.

An alternative could be to place the SVG as part of the CSS as a background in the content.

```css
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width=".1" d="M 0 5 Q 15 -5 30 5" pathLength="2" />
  <text class="title is-4" font-size="2" dominant-baseline="hanging" text-anchor="middle">
    <textPath href="#MyPath" startOffset="1">
      Curved Title
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
<div style="background:silver">More content</div>
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width=".1" d="M 0 5 Q 15 -5 30 5" pathLength="2" />
  <text class="title is-4" font-size="2" dominant-baseline="hanging" text-anchor="middle">
    <textPath href="#MyPath" startOffset="1">
      Curved Title
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
<div style="background:silver">More content</div>
```

Comment: You can also use `<defs></defs>` to show only the text without the curve.

Comment: @EvreuxPendragon like OP also points out in the question the stroke is just for the illustration/example. I'm sure OP is already aware of this.

Comment: I used stroke="none" inside the <path></path> element to remove the stroke.